# Electron app - logging to file in production

Tags: node.js, logging, electron

I want to get logs if something wrong happens to my electron app when in production mode i.e after giving .exe file to a user wrt windows platform.

How to go about it, how can i basically write my errors to a file which will be in cyclic in nature.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at [electron log](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log)

```
// Setup file logging
const log = require('electron-log');
log.transports.file.level = 'info';
log.transports.file.file = __dirname + 'log.log';

// Log a message
log.info('log message');
```

---

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments the "log.transports.file.file" is deprecated.

Instead I would suggest to use the following method.

```
log.transports.file.resolvePath = () => __dirname + "/log.log";
```

Comment: file.file is deprecated it says.

Comment: As mentioned from the comment above the `log.transports.file.file` is deprecated.

Instead I would suggest to use the following method.

`log.transports.file.resolvePath = () => __dirname + "/logs/log.log";`

Answer (score 1):

Create a file next to you electron.js called **logger.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const log = require('electron-log');

log.transports.file.resolvePath = () => path.join(__dirname, '/logsmain.log');
log.transports.file.level = "info";

exports.log = (entry) => log.info(entry)
```

then on your app

```
const logger = require('electron').remote.require('./logger');
logger.log("some text")
```

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look here:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/net-log

```
const { netLog } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  await netLog.startLogging('/path/to/net-log')
  // After some network events
  const path = await netLog.stopLogging()
  console.log('Net-logs written to', path)
})
```

Comment: When reading the documentation located at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/net-log, it seems that this is meant to be used to log network calls? and not so much application logging. Can someone confirm?

Comment: @sdec yep, `netLog` is just for the network logging, e.g. see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/network-logging-in-electronjs/